# Bash replace string between tokens

Tags: regex, linux, sed

How to use sed and regex to replace the text between a variable number of one token?

Example of input:

`/abc/bcd/cde/`

Expected output:

`/../../../`

**Tried**:

Command: `echo "/abc/bcd/cde/" | sed 's/\/.*\//\/..\//g'` output: `/../`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace every substring of non-slashes (`[^/]\+`) with two dots:

```
$> echo "/abc/bcd/cde/" | sed 's$[^/]\+$..$g'
# => /../../../
```

Answer (score 2):

Using perl and [*look around assertions*](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) :

```
$ perl -pe 's|(?<=/)\w{3}(?=/)|..|g' file
/../../../
```

Using sed :

```
$ echo "/abc/bcd/cde/" | sed -E 's|[a-z]{3}|..|g'
/../../../
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on @Gilles Quenot implementation but, capturing any alpha numeric chars between //

```
$ echo "/abddc/bcqsdd/cdde/" | sed -E 's|(/)?[^/]+/|\1../|g'
```